# How to show tooltip by data index on d3js charts? (with no mouseover event)

Tags: d3.js

For example I have this chart http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369. 
There is a tooltip on mouseover event. So there is a coordinates to display the tooltip.

But I want to display the tooltip(and change the node color) by hitting on button with the node id (by date or price). So there is no mouse event and no coordinates pageX for the tooltip. How can I do it with no coordinates but by the node index?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: append both the SVG and the tooltip divs to the same container.

Step two: set the ID for each circle using their indices. Remember: IDs are **unique**.

```
.attr("id", (d, i) => "circle" + i)
```

Step three: set the values of the buttons to match the IDs:

```
<button value="circle1">Circle 1</button>
<button value="circle4">Circle 4</button>
<button value="circle6">Circle 6</button>
```

Step four (*"I can give you more..."*): When clicking the buttons, get the data of the circle...

```
var thisData = d3.select("#" + this.value).data()[0];
```

... and position the div wherever you want regarding the container:

```
div.html(formatTime(thisData.date) + "<br/>" + thisData.close)
    .style("left", 500 + "px")
    .style("top", 50 + "px");
```

Here is the modified bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/201bac3383aed438c1e43928db4a7a1c

EDIT: If you want to position the tooltip at the same position of the circle element, you can select the element...

```
var thisNode = d3.select("#" + this.value);
```

... and get its `cx` and `cy` attributes with a getter. Here is another bl.ocks showing this: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/ed5292e172c2cf38a9df1d735876f376

Comment: Thank you!. But is there a way to set the XY div position as it is set with the onmouse event?

Comment: Do you mean at different positions for each circle? Check my edit (and sorry for the *New kids on the block* reference. Not my kind of music, but I couldn't help...)

Comment: Yes, that is it. Listened to that song. Not my kind of music too)